# iOS - How to manage dependencies of a framework during it's development using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am currently developing an iOS framework (let's say `MyFramework`) which internally uses 3rd party framework, let's say `Alamofire`for some of it's functionalities. How can I install this dependency using cocoapods and use it during the development of the framework. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `MyFramework` is also going to be distributed via Cocoapods: create a hosting app for your framework, and include it as a so-called development pod:

```
 pod 'MyFramework', :path => '.../path/to/MyFramework'
```

In `MyFramework.podspec`, mention Alamofire as a dependency:

```
 s.dependency 'Alamofire'
```

Run `pod install`.